# How to interpret Law of conservation of strangeness?

Tags: conservation-laws, standard-model, weak-interaction

Is there a recent explanation of Law of conservation of strangeness? and why does it not work for reactions taking long times like $10^{-10}$ seconds?

Comment: I have edited your post to include mathjax but either you wrote long instead of short or you put a minus sign in by mistake.  could you check it please, you can delete the minus sign no problem

Comment: Minus sign is correct. Thank You for editing. I am new and didn't knew mathjax option was present.

Comment: I don't know the field, but does a time of $10^{-10} $ seconds make sense as a long time, because that's what your question says? No need to reply, it looks odd to me, but maybe $10^{-10} $ is a long time in this context. I will leave it to you, best of luck with it.  Mathjax reference page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @CountTo10: $10^{-10}$ seconds is about the lifetime of a strange quark in most hadrons. On elementary timescales that's a long time!

Answer (score 3):

It isn't true that processes that change the strangeness can't be faster than $10^{-10}$ seconds. For example a top quark can decay into a strange quark, which changes the strangeness by $+1$, and that takes around $5 \times 10^{-25}$ seconds. However it is mostly true, and this is why.

Incidentally you might want to have a look at the Wikipedia article on strangeness, [where the conservation of strangeness is discussed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness#Conservation).

Strangeness is the **net** number of strange quarks i.e. the number of strange quarks minus the number of antistrange quarks. There are no processes involving the strong and electromagnetic forces that can change the net number of strange quarks, or indeed any other types of quark. They can only create or destroy strange-antistrange pairs, and this leaves the strangeness unchanged.

Weak interactions can change the net number of strange quarks, but they are usually (relatively) slow. So for example the strange quark decay to an up quark and $W^-$ boson via the weak force takes around $10^{-10}$ seconds. This is the reason for the time limit that you mention. Most processes that take less than $10^{-10}$ seconds involve only the strong and EM forces and therefore those processes can't change the strangeness.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on the statement in the first paragraph? It seems contradictory in view of what you say in the rest of your answer. What is the mechanism that causes this extremely short time scale, if the usual weak interaction usually produces a much longer time scale?

Comment: Is there any process involving weak interaction that preserve the strangeness? I can't find an answer to it on net or anywhere else, all saying is that weak interaction change strangeness by 1 unit.

Answer (score -6):

> How to interpret Law of conservation of strangeness?

There is no such law. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness): *"Noting that collisions seemed to always produce pairs of these particles, it was postulated that a new conserved quantity, dubbed 'strangeness', was preserved during their creation, but **not** conserved in their decay"*.

> Is there a recent explanation of Law of conservation of strangeness? and why does it not work for reactions taking long times like $10^{−10}$ seconds?

I don't currently know of a satisfactory explanation for the preservation of strangeness during particle creation. Because I can't currently explain what strangeness is. Strangeness was introduced because some particles such as [kaons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon) took longer to decay than others. As for how this actually works, I can't say in a fashion that will satisfy you. The Wikipedia article says this: *"The strange antiquark of the kaon transmutes into an up antiquark by the emission of a W+ boson; the W+ boson subsequently decays into a down antiquark and an up quark"*. But there's no explanation of how or why this happens, and no explanation of how it can happen when the W+ boson has a mass of 80GeV, which is far more than the kaon or the resultant pions. And there's no explanation as to why a billionth of a second later, all the strangeness is gone. Sorry.

Comment: It is perhaps not a good idea to propose an answer when one then needs to admit that one doesn't understand the work.

Comment: I've removed some comments that discussed another user.

Comment: It seems to me that the "lack of knowledge" discussed in this answer is a philosophical statement rather than an admission of ignorance of the field.  "Strangeness" is a shorthand for a collection of related observed phenomena. We know a lot about what particles and fields with nonzero strangeness *do*, but that doesn't tell us what strangeness *is*. You could say the same about charm and the other flavor quantum numbers. There's not an explanation in the standard model for why there are three generations of quarks or leptons; it's just what we observe.

Comment: [People used to describe electricity the same way: we know what it does, but not what it is](https://books.google.com/books?id=FztOBnYFYWwC&pg=PA304 "A 1941 book about an 1885 experience."). Nowadays we turn that around and say "electricity is what causes lightning and static cling and makes circuits work." Strangeness is the same sort of thing: a fundamental type of charge whose behavior we can describe very, very well but whose explanation is "well, it's a thing that we see happening." Whether that's enough to tell you what strangeness "is": that depends on your epistemology.

Comment: @rob : Cross my heart and hope to die, I know what electricity is, and what an electron is, and what electromagnetic charge is. It isn't fundamental by the way. But I don't know what strangeness is.